# VirtualHost working only in home page with Codeigniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, virtualhost

I'm facing some problems with Virtual Hosts under Apache 2.2.

I want to host development versions of some sites in my local environment (some of them using codeigniter) and be able to access them using a ".dev" extension, so I can go to:

```
- http://myproject.dev to access the local version or
- http://myproject.com to access production version
```

I've set up some name-based virtual hosts as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost localhost  
<VirtualHost localhost>  
    DocumentRoot ".../workspace.web/" 
    ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost myproject.dev  
<VirtualHost myproject.dev>  
    DocumentRoot ".../workspace.web/myproject.com/htdocs"
    ServerName myproject.dev 
</VirtualHost>
```

and set my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   psychologuenice.dev
```

The home page is working fine, but subdirectories are crashing in codeigniter. For example

```
myproject.dev/whatever
```

returns a 404 error.

I'm not sure if any of the rules in htaccess could be causing this, or is just due to a bad understanding of what I'm doing here. My htaccess looks like this:

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|images|css|js|captcha|inc|html|tmp|captcha)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# BEGIN Turn ETags Off
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off
```

Could someone give any clue?